# Nested JSON Find - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So the issue I have:

I have been given a data source like such

```
{
  "Class": "ScanLayers",
  "ExportVersion": 1,
  "Layers": {
    "0150e77a-9af5-ccc1-aa82-89793c1c4067": {
        "Class": "ScanTiles",
        "ExportVersion": 3,
        "MetadataUUID": "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c539e59019c3",
        "Scan": "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-aa82-89793c1c4067",
        "ScanName": "ATT021"
    },
    "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067": {
        "Class": "ScanTiles",
        "ExportVersion": 3,
        "MetadataUUID": "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c5sad876adc3",
        "Scan": "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067",
        "ScanName": "ATT022"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to find a certain scan name and then return its parent. So for example. I want to find `"ATT022"`. I would get a return id of the **UUID** of `"0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067"` I understand if I had the **UUID** this would be easy to return the child. But I do not understand how to find the child to return the parent.

Comment: You want to search only inside the `Layers` array or in the whole object? How many level there could be? Are `ScanName`s unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the native [**Array.prototype.find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the key from the [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (or `null`) for the criteria you want like this:

```js
var obj = {
  'Class': "ScanLayers",
  'ExportVersion': 1,
  'Layers': {
    "0150e77a-9af5-ccc1-aa82-89793c1c4067": {
      "Class": "ScanTiles",
      "ExportVersion": 3,
      "MetadataUUID": "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c539e59019c3",
      "Scan": "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-aa82-89793c1c4067",
      "ScanName": "ATT021"
    },
    "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067": {
      "Class": "ScanTiles",
      "ExportVersion": 3,
      "MetadataUUID": "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c5sad876adc3",
      "Scan": "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067",
      "ScanName": "ATT022"
    }
  }
}

var scanName = "ATT022";

var found = Object.keys(obj.Layers).find(function(layerKey) {
  return obj.Layers[layerKey].ScanName == scanName;
});

if (found)
  console.log(found);
else
  console.log("Nothing found!");
```

Comment: This is what I was headed for. Very simple. Now only problem I have is this json is not returned from API. They are stored in files. But I have been out of the game for quite some time. looks like XMLHttpRequest does not allow local content anymore? So essentially quick follow up question. how do I load my json file (that's local) into variable.

Comment: @GrafixMasta You mean running on `localhost` or `file://`?

Comment: file. We are trying to keep this all off webserver for time being. just a local app no webserver needed.

Comment: @GrafixMasta But which one? a localhost like wamp or just `file://` like just opening the .html page into chrome?

Comment: file:// .. Again. No webserver is being used right now. Once we publish the app to our client then we will use a webserver

Comment: @GrafixMasta I think all the answers provided what you wanted. At least what you've asked in your question.

Comment: mrlew. I didn't say they did not. I agree with you. But at the same time. This is more optimal and optimized in my opinion and everyone has a right to their opinion. yes?

Comment: Well for now you can emulate a local server. On windows `cd` to your directory and then type this command line `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` But you have to install python first.

Comment: @GrafixMasta sure, but other answers received a downvote, didn't get it. ibrahim's answer is great, but `.find()` is still a loop that breaks when finds the first. Same thing in terms of performance, IMHO.

Comment: @mrlew `.find()` is probably using an optimized search algorithm not just looping from 0 to array.length

Comment: @mrlew I didn't neither!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir So basically if i install wamp on this machine it would then be able to make an xmlhttprequest. no problem?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you sure? didn't know that... I'll find some benchmark. I thougt it was only a polyfill/abstraction

Comment: probably some mass downvoter, without feedback :( nevermind :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  

i tried the following

var sceneJsonForProject = (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': "pathrojson/jsonfile.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();

did not work. i have installed wamp :(

Comment: @GrafixMasta Is the url correct? Check the console! Is there any errors?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: I got an error that talked about xmlhttp not being able to be used. but i changed my original path on console log and i found the issue. path wrong :( thanks.

Comment: Just for note: I got curious about `.find` performance and created this benchmark (create 1M record of OP's data). My conclusion: same thing that iterate over keys, in browser. In nodejs, .find is slower. Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/sw42z0ky/

Comment: @mrlew I think you're right! `[/*...*/].find((e, index) => console.log(index));` go from 0 to array.length. So I guess it's just an abstraction. I tought that since `sort` uses the quick sort algorithm, `find` will follow the same thing. But it's just an old `for` loop.

Comment: But i think GrafixMasta chose this answer because it's more compact. It is recommended to use those abstractions anyway (`forEach`, `map`, `reduc` ...).

Comment: Yes, I didn't know either, this question just made me curious about the performance :) In order to achieve his goal, he'll have to loop and break when the first is found (using find or manual iteration). There is not another way...

Answer (score 0):

If that's exactly your data schema, you can use a function like that (using ES6 syntax):

```
var obj = {
    "Class": "ScanLayers",
    "ExportVersion": 1,
    "Layers": {
        "0150e77a-9af5-ccc1-aa82-89793c1c4067": {
            "Class": "ScanTiles",
            "ExportVersion": 3,
            "MetadataUUID": "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c539e59019c3",
            "Scan": "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-aa82-89793c1c4067",
            "ScanName": "ATT021"
        },
        "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067": {
            "Class": "ScanTiles",
            "ExportVersion": 3,
            "MetadataUUID": "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c5sad876adc3",
            "Scan": "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067",
            "ScanName": "ATT022"
        }
    }
}

const getIdByScanName = (obj, name) => {
    for (id in obj['Layers']) {
        if (obj['Layers'][id]['ScanName'] === name) return id
    }
}

console.log(getIdByScanName(obj, "ATT021")) //0150e77a-9af5-ccc1-aa82-89793c1c4067
console.log(getIdByScanName(obj, "ATT022")) //0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067
console.log(getIdByScanName(obj, "ATT023")) //undefined (when key not found)
```

---

**Note:** In your question, one comma is missing between the `Layers` subobject keys (probably a typo).

Answer (score 0):

I create this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kokeronoyo/edit?js,console) for your problem.

you just need to pass 3 parameters to this function, data source, type and string

```
checkName = function (obj,type,string) {
 for( var key in obj.Layers){
  if(obj.Layers[key][type] === string){
   return obj.Layers[key];
  }
 } 
}

console.log(checkName(dataSource,'ScanName','ATT022'))
```

and it would return something like this ...

```
{
  Class: "ScanTiles",
  ExportVersion: 3,
  MetadataUUID: "90a23cdc-9b2f-4788-935d-c5sad876adc3",
  Scan: "0150e77a-9af5-4b77-bb43-89793c1a4067",
  ScanName: "ATT022"
}
```

Comment: Amir thank you for this. You have given me a thought about what I may need for a different thing. But again this is using a loop function and would take in my opinion the overhead will be too significant.